# Cursor of SQLHelper returns number with exponent

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I dont know why. My data in SQLite Displays as `96665488558.5` but when I used `Cursor` it displays as `9.66655e+10`

This is my code on testing

```
Cursor data = myDb.get_exp(email);
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("Amount","" + data.getString(5)); //9.66655e+10 it displays
        }
```

This is the code I used to display a data with comma separated.

`credentials.doubleToStringwithDecimal(Float.parseFloat(data.getString(5)));`

and this is the function structure

```
public static String doubleToStringwithDecimal(double d) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        formatter.applyPattern("#,###.##");
        return formatter.format(d);
    }
```

Now that code displays the data incorrectly because if value with e+10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Log.v("Amount", "" + new BigDecimal(data.getString(5)).toPlainString());
```

**Edit:**

```
Cursor data = myDb.get_exp(email);
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("Amount", new DecimalFormat("#,###.##").format(data.getDouble(5))); 
        }
```

Comment: @myownemail do you store value as double ?

Comment: actually no sir. because all the data i inputed is saved in database that has a datatype of DECIMAL(16,2) for example i will save 100000000.88 i will see that.

Comment: i just retrieve it but what happens is that it turns with e+10 at the end losing my decimals

Comment: @myownemail can you please check if you can get value using data.getDouble(5) instead of using getString?

Comment: Hi sir done testing it and it is now displayed correctly. But it will be a a lot of work if i updated it 1 by 1 how can I use my function to convert it so it will be less code and i will still in tact with getString

Comment: @myownemail sure you can do it,how are you doing it right now? can you please update it in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184706/discussion-between-mayur-gajra-and-myown-email).